# Opam doesn't download sources when building locally

Tags: url, ocaml, archive, opam

I'm trying to add some patches to the `llvm` Opam package, but I'm having issues testing it because it seems like running `opam install .` from the package root ignores the `url` section and doesn't download & decompress the source archive, thus failing when applying patches.

This is the `opam` file for reference:

```
opam-version: "2.0"
maintainer: "Kate <kit.ty.kate@disroot.org>"
authors: [
  "whitequark <whitequark@whitequark.org>"
  "The LLVM team"
]
license: "MIT"
doc: "http://llvm.moe/ocaml"
bug-reports: "http://llvm.org/bugs/"
dev-repo: "git+http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git"
homepage: "http://llvm.moe"
install: [
  ["bash" "-ex" "install.sh" "%{conf-llvm:config}%" lib "%{conf-cmake:cmd}%" make]
]
depends: [
  "ocaml" {>= "4.00.0"}
  "ctypes" {>= "0.4"}
  "ounit" {with-test}
  "ocamlfind" {build}
  "conf-llvm" {build & = version}
  "conf-python-2-7" {build}
  "conf-cmake" {build}
]
patches: [
  "fix-shared.patch"
]
synopsis: "The OCaml bindings distributed with LLVM"
description: "Note: LLVM should be installed first."
extra-files: [
  ["link-META.patch" "md5=ef4ebb8706be2ed402f31fc351d7dc75"]
  ["install.sh" "md5=683ec0478ee422a57dcd3716277b3ef3"]
  ["fix-shared.patch" "md5=dce86b1db352332968ceb6d042b408a8"]
  ["META.patch" "md5=1d0af08bab7a0f831f68849b6556e414"]
  ["add-buildfence-llvm.ml.patch" "md5=a3bc667bd2fc937ee51c3b9d33b8ad63"]
  ["add-buildfence-llvm.mli.patch" "md5=99c739d74deeb1b990fe63cf914fc479"]
  ["add-buildfence-llvm_ocaml.c.patch" "md5=a29282f2e1e435abff57cecfd269ccb9"]
]
url {
  src: "https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-11.1.0/llvm-11.1.0.src.tar.xz"
  checksum: "sha256=ce8508e318a01a63d4e8b3090ab2ded3c598a50258cc49e2625b9120d4c03ea5"
}
```

and this is the result of running `opam install . -vvv` on the package root:

```
Processing  1/1: [llvm.11.0.0: rsync]
+ /usr/bin/rsync "-rLptgoDrvc" "--exclude" ".git" "--exclude" "_darcs" "--exclude" ".hg" "--exclude" ".#*" "--exclude" "_opam*" "--delete" "--delete-excluded" "/home/frabert/opam-repository/packages/llvm/llvm.11.0.0/" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/sources/llvm"
- sending incremental file list
- ./
- out
- 
- sent 828 bytes  received 39 bytes  1,734.00 bytes/sec
- total size is 19,120  speedup is 22.05
[llvm.11.0.0] synchronised from file:///home/frabert/opam-repository/packages/llvm/llvm.11.0.0
+ /usr/bin/lsb_release "-s" "-r"
- 18.04
+ /usr/bin/ocamlc "-vnum"
- 4.05.0
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗ install llvm 11.0.0*
+ /usr/bin/rsync "-rLptgoDrvc" "--exclude" ".git" "--exclude" "_darcs" "--exclude" ".hg" "--exclude" ".#*" "--exclude" "_opam*" "--delete" "--delete-excluded" "/home/frabert/opam-repository/packages/llvm/llvm.11.0.0/" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/sources/llvm"
- sending incremental file list
- ./
- opam
- out
- files/
- files/META.patch
- files/add-buildfence-llvm.ml.patch
- files/add-buildfence-llvm.mli.patch
- files/add-buildfence-llvm_ocaml.c.patch
- files/fix-shared.patch
- files/install.sh
- files/link-META.patch
- 
- sent 20,648 bytes  received 202 bytes  41,700.00 bytes/sec
- total size is 19,775  speedup is 0.95
[llvm.11.0.0] synchronised from file:///home/frabert/opam-repository/packages/llvm/llvm.11.0.0

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
+ /bin/cp "-PRp" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/sources/llvm" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/link-META.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/link-META.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/install.sh" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/install.sh"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/fix-shared.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/fix-shared.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/add-buildfence-llvm_ocaml.c.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/add-buildfence-llvm_ocaml.c.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/add-buildfence-llvm.mli.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/add-buildfence-llvm.mli.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/add-buildfence-llvm.ml.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/add-buildfence-llvm.ml.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/overlay/llvm/files/META.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/META.patch"
+ /bin/cp "/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0/fix-shared.patch" "/home/frabert/.opam/log/processed-patch-13793-c743ac"
Processing  1/2: [llvm: patch]
+ /usr/bin/patch "-p1" "-i" "/home/frabert/.opam/log/processed-patch-13793-c743ac" (CWD=/home/frabert/.opam/4.11.1/.opam-switch/build/llvm.11.0.0)
- can't find file to patch at input line 5
- Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
- The text leading up to this was:
- --------------------------
- |diff --git a/cmake/modules/AddOCaml.cmake b/cmake/modules/AddOCaml.cmake
- |index 554046b20..b27cbd36c 100644
- |--- a/cmake/modules/AddOCaml.cmake
- |+++ b/cmake/modules/AddOCaml.cmake
- --------------------------
- File to patch: 
- Skip this patch? [y] 
- Skipping patch.
- 1 out of 1 hunk ignored


<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build llvm 11.0.0
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed
```

Is this a known problem?

EDIT: Clarification regarding the workflow

I have a local git clone of the opam-repository, of which I have edited and committed the llvm.11.0.0 package definition.

To test the edits, I run `opam install .` from inside the `llvm.11.0.0` directory which contains the `opam` file.

Comment: No, it is not a known problem. Can you describe your problem in more detail? What makes you think that files are not downloaded? I only see that patch is not applied, because no corresponding files were found. Also, common errors are: (1) forgot to commit, (2) forgot to `opam update`. If it is not the case then, please, describe your workflow.

Comment: @ivg Regarding the common issues: the changes have been committed to a repo, and I did run `opam update` beforehand. I think nothing is being downloaded because opam tries to apply the patches almost immediately, whereas I would expect to have to wait for the archive to download and be extracted first, and it's not even a "small" archive. Also, when installing the upstream `llvm` package with `-vvv`, I can see the output of something like wget/curl, but I can't really see of what since the filename is renamed to a temporary one.

Comment: Update to previous comment: I did, in fact, check that when running `opam install llvm`, opam first downloads the file specified in the `url` section before applying the patches, using curl. This does not happen when I run `opam install .`

Comment: it won't download the same archive again, because it is in the cache. But the archive is correct and is verfied by its md5sum. So I think you're looking in a wrong direction. I wonder which package do you pin? And again, please, describe your workflow. It is totally not clear where do you run `opam pin .` and so on. You might also consider filing an issue with a question in the ocaml/opam repository.

Comment: I have added some notes regarding the workflow. Regarding the cache: I can actually see that `opam install llvm` (after removing the pin) _always_ downloads the archive. Even then, I actually cleared the downloads-cache directory and the `opam install .` command still won't download the archive, so I don't think that's the only issue.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what is going wrong. Not sure if it is a bug or unclear documentation or both, but you're pinning the wrong repository. I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong workflow, as hinted correctly by @ivg

The correct one, though, appears to be the one described here: https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/4654

Basically, I needed to add a local repository, and then install the llvm package as usual.

```
opam repo add local ~/opam-repository
opam install llvm
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct<sup>1</sup> workflow for changing a package definition in the `ocaml/opam-repository` is the following.

1. clone the opam-repository

```
git clone git@github.com:ocaml/opam-repository.git
```

2. add the local repository to the opam repo list

```
opam repo add local ./opam-repository
```

3. make a copy of the package that you would like to change (using llvm as the working example), we will use `-<patch>` since we're just adding a patch, not releasing a new version,

```
cd opam-repository/packages/llvm/
cp -r llvm.11.0.0/ llvm.11.0.0-1
```

4. work with the patched version ...
5. commit the work

```
git add llvm.11.0.0-1
git commit -m 'wip'
```

6. test it

```
opam update
opam install llvm
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Well, at least it is the workflow that I am using everyday :)

Comment: I'm assuming I'd need to pin the llvm package, but to what directory? The `opam-repository` root, the `llvm` dir, or the `llvm.11.0.0-1`? Or should I `opam repository add` the local `opam-repository`?

Comment: oops, I forgot the main ingredient, yes, you need to add your locally cloned repo to the opam repository list.